# Not able to log in through db.auth(..) method

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

i have created a user with the following credential:

```
  db.addUser( { user: "superadmin3",
      pwd: "superadmin3",
      roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin","userAdminAnyDatabase","clusterAdmin"  ]
    } )
```

Than started mongod with --auth:true

but I am not able to login when I say:

```
db.auth("superadmin3","superadmin3");
```

I get the following error:

```
 error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on test.system.users", "code" : 16550 } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:128
```

I want to create a credential for all the databases present.

Answer (score 2):

You have to authenticate against admin database while the user exists there (If you followed the instructions here : [DOC](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/)).

So

```
use admin
db.auth("superadmin3","superadmin3");
```

will work.

To create a user in a specified db you have to create the user there (so use dbname and adduser after) . Only a user with useradmin roles will be able to do this.